# How to show divs in one column on web and two columns on mobile?

Tags: css

I have for divs:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

On desktop, they are positioned like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

On mobile, I would like them to be positioned like this:

```
1  3
2  4
```

if i do

```
div{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    clear left;
}
#3,#4{
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

They end up like this:

```
1
2 3
  4
```

The divs are dynamically generated, so if I can avoid adding additional markup, that would be very good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w74fsedj/3/)

Given the HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div id="1">1</div>
    <div id="2">2</div>
    <div id="3">3</div>
    <div id="4">4</div>
</div>
```

You could use the CSS:

```
.wrapper > div {
    border:1px solid; /* <-- not needed, used to show div locations */
    height:100px; /* <-- not needed, used to show div locations */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {  /* <-- apply styles on certian screen size */
    .wrapper {
        -webkit-column-count:2; /* <--put the divs in two columns */
        -moz-column-count:2; /* <--put the divs in two columns */
        column-count:2; /* <--put the divs in two columns */
    }
}
```

Changing the `300px` for whatever you deem a mobile device screen to be

Comment: Isn't `div:not(.wrapper)` overkill? Why not `.wrapper > div`? +1

Comment: @iambriansreed - absolutely, changed- originally shoe-horned it in another example :P

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but I thought I'd give you a different perspective and actually a more commonly used one as well. If you apply bootstrap framework (even if not to a global extend) but you can gut out the css the is valid to your problem, you will be able to do this a lot more comfortably. without getting into css specifity. All you have to do is make proper us of `col-md-12` and `col-xs-6`

See **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwbmLa)**

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would simply use media queries to change the width of the divs. This would allow you to avoid adding more markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/14ecjy7n/1/

```
div {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
}
@media all and (max-width: 639px) {
    div {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 640px) {
    div {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```